# Testing first differenced time series - trend or not?

Tags: r, unit-root, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a question on testing for stationarity with the ADF test, in order to determine the order of integration.

We do have a time series that looks in plot(df) obviously trending at level and has a high fluctuation ("drift+trend"). We therefore assume, that we have to apply following script from vars to get an appropriate ADF test result:

```
ur.df(df, type = "trend", selectlags = "BIC")
```

Assume the test finds that the time series is not stationary (,as the plot already suggested). We therefore proceed testing the *first difference* of the time series:

```
ur.df(diff(df), type = "trend", selectlags = "BIC")
```

Is it okay to consider "**trend**" in the test, when we know that diff(df) *looks stationary* in plot(diff(df)?

Comment: The ADF test like all tests have built-in assumptions in order for them to be valid. The big print giveth the small print taketh away! . Find out what these assumptions are . Make sure your data meets the assumptions e.g. no outliers ,no seasonal pulses , no step/level shifts (intercept changes) , no need for  transformations like logs , no need to be worried about deterministic change points in error variance etc.

Comment: Check out earlier questions tagged with the [tag:augmented-dickey-fuller] tag to see if your question might have been answered before.

Comment: I discovered this answer here, though it was not confirmed by anyone else: [Link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285982/augmented-dickey-fuller-specification-with-levels-and-first-differences)

Comment: From that argumentation I would conclude (and Update my post, if you can confirm): The time series has to be visually inspected after first differencing. If it shows no trend, the right model should be: `ur.df(diff(df), type = "drift", selectlags = "BIC")`. Correct?

Comment: @RichardHardy I looked up some of your posts and others on the topic but remain unclear. The time series we're talking about looks very trending and is *actually* found to be "stationary" when tested with: `ur.df(df, type = "trend", selectlags = "BIC")`. From that view, would we conclude I(0) or I(1)? It's so hard to believe that I conclude this time series to be I(0). I don't get entirely the discussions on "trend stationarity" and what it really means for my models (i.e. is the problem solved by including "trend" into every of my AR/VAR/VECM models, while proceeding with variables at level?